# Apache web server is not working

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, web-server

To apache web server installation process i followed below mentioned steps

```
tar xzf httpd-2.4.7.tar.gz
 ./configure
 make
 make install
```

all the above steps execited. But when i trying to know the status of this server.
 showing error

```
[root@localhost httpd-2.4.7]#  /etc/init.d/httpd stop
 bash: /etc/init.d/httpd: No such file or directory
 [root@localhost httpd-2.4.7]#  /etc/init.d/httpd start
 bash: /etc/init.d/httpd: No such file or directory
```

I also checked this package is installed or not by using

```
[root@localhost httpd-2.4.7]# yum list h*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.net.in
 * epel: epel.mirror.net.in
 * extras: centos.mirror.net.in
 * jpackage-generic: mirror.ibcp.fr
 * jpackage-generic-updates: mirror.ibcp.fr
 * updates: centos.mirror.net.in
Available Packages
httpd.x86_64                      2.2.15-29.el6.centos                      base
```

and also i checked in browser by using
`http://localhost` it showing error This webpage is not available.
What is the wrong.Did you any one face this problem? how to resolve. Please let me know

Comment: What type of OS/Distro are you using?

Comment: it seems like centos because of the tag

Comment: ya centos I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you missed this

```
chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on
```

---

to start and stop your service you can type

```
service httpd stop
```

or

```
service httpd start
```

or

```
service httpd restart
```

---

**the best way to achieve your needs is this:**

to install httpd you can simply do this on centos, redhat, linux

```
yum install httpd
```

note: httpd should installed on centos by default!

to set the apache service to start on boot

```
chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on
```

now enable name-based virtual hosting on port 80, open the httpd configuration file located at

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

un-comment the line containing the text NameVirtualHost *:80 and save the file.
now restart the Apache HTTP Server daemon:

```
service httpd restart
```

note: Ignore the "NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts" warning for now.

visit localhost to see the apache test page.

Comment: `[root@localhost httpd-2.4.7]# chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on
error reading information on service httpd: No such file or directory and `[root@localhost httpd-2.4.7]# service httpd stop
httpd: unrecognized service
`
`

Comment: you are using centos? you installed httpd via yum? is there a test site on http://localhost? another apache service is already running?

Comment: Thank you! your suggestion works fine.. but how to know the where it installed

Comment: How to know the ports?

Comment: for the ports just play with "netstat -anp" or "lsof -i". to get to know where apache is installed try "ps -ef | grep apache". plz upvote :P

Comment: i don't have that much points to upvoote sorry

Comment: no prob. you got the path?

Comment: ya i got it.using locate httpd

Comment: you have any idea about how to run Perl cgi script on apache server

Comment: create a new question and i will answer it :) or just read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560749/how-do-i-configure-apache2-to-run-perl-cgi-scripts

Comment: where can i ask question.. either here or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/

Comment: wherever you want :)